# find the limitation $u_{n}$, which $u_{n+1}=(1-\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{u_{n})}^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\left\{\begin{matrix}u_{0}=0,5 \\ u_{n+1}=(1-\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{u_{n}})^{n} \end{matrix}\right.$

find lim $u_{n}$

It is not hard to figure out the limit is $\frac{1}{e}$.

I try to prove with n is large enough $u_{n}>u_{n+1}$ 
because $u_{n}>0$ then the sequence has limit.

but when try to prove $u_{n}-u_{n+1}>0$, there are so many stucks.

The equation is very complicate.

Some when help me to prove it,

Answer (score 4):

First, we see that $0\leq u_n\leq 1$ for all $n$.

Now, 
$$u_{n+1}=( 1-\frac{u_n^{1/n}}{n})^n\geq (1-\frac{1}{n})^n$$
But hence we have:
$\displaystyle u_{n+1}\geq (1-\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$, hence $\displaystyle \frac{u_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)}}{n+1}\geq \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, and $\displaystyle u_{n+2}\leq (1-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)})^{n+1}$; Now replacing $n$ by $n-1$ in the last inequality, we get:

$$(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n-1)n})^n\geq u_{n+1}\geq (1-\frac{1}{n})^n$$

and it is easy to finish.